# Wiremock Hystrix failure on upgrade

Tags: hystrix, wiremock

We have a few tests using wiremock, using rule:

```
@Rule
    public WireMockRule rules = new WireMockRule(PORT);
```

It is an old app and used wiremock version 1.7. Now that we upgraded it to the 2.4.1, some of the tests fail.
The actual Http Query is done through Hystrix, which might be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Hystrix. 
If your response files size is not matched with the content length in mapping file, wiremock has problem handling it. Make sure you have the correct content length, or just remove the content length from mapping file.

Answer (score 0):

When Hystrix enabled with WireMock, stubs do not work stable. Hystrix timeout should be increased in your properties. This example is for isolation thread.

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds = 10000
```